# WSO2 AM: External JWT - 900908 Resource forbidden

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, wso2, wso2-api-manager

We use **WSO2 AM** based on the Docker image wso2/wso2am:4.1.0. Creating, publishing and subscribing to APIs works fine out of the box.

**Task:**

We want to integrate with an external OAuth provider. Our SPA handles the login and eventually retrieves the access token from the external OAuth provider. Instead of generating our own tokens, we want to use the already issued token(s) of the external OAuth provider, to enable access on a specific API in WSO2 AM.
Apart from validating the JWT (exp and signature), there are no additional requirements.

**Approach so far:**

Without any modifications we receive the following logs and responses while accessing and API with an unknown JWT, as expected:

> WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Invalid Credentials

```
{
  "code": "900901",
  "message": "Invalid Credentials",
  "description": "Access failure for API: /test/v1, version: v1 status: (900901) - Invalid Credentials. Make sure you have provided the correct security credentials"
}
```

After following the documenation at [JWT Access Tokens - WSO2 API Manager Documentation 4.1.0](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/access-token-types/jwt-tokens/#signature-validation) we obviously managed to basically validate the external token. Log message and response did change to:

> WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Resource forbidden

```
{
  "code": "900908",
  "message": "Resource forbidden ",
  "description": "Resource forbidden "
}
```

Unfortunately the documentation ends here, or I'm not able to find the proper follow up steps. We probably need to create an Application, tie it to the external OAuth provider and subscribe to the API.

I tried to create a new Application in the DeveloperPortal, but apart from configuring the local OAuth2 settings, there are no available options to use an external OAuth provider.
I also tried to create a new Service Provider as described in [Provisioning Out-of-Band OAuth Clients - WSO2 API Manager Documentation 4.1.0](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/provisioning-out-of-band-oauth-clients/#step-2-create-an-external-oauth2-client), which at least gave me the option to configure it in an Application in the DeveloperPortal. But apart from the JWKS settings in the Service Provider, I was not able to find any hints on how to tie it to the external OAuth provider.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource forbidden error comes when there is no valid subscription to the API. How subscription validation happens in the APIM is, after validating the token, it uses the client id value in the JWT to find the mapped dev portal application. Then it checks whether there is a valid subscription to the API using that application. In this case, this step is failing due to missing a valid subscription. We probably have to revisit this section and modify the content.

Instead of using this method, I would suggest exchanging your external JWT with JWT  recognized by APIM using the JWT bearer grant type. This is a blog [post](https://chamilaadhi.medium.com/use-jwts-generated-from-external-parties-to-invoke-apis-in-the-wso2-api-manager-e92b372de192) I have written on doing this using an external JWT. Also, the official document has an example using WSO2 IS (see [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/grant-types/jwt-grant/)).

Comment: Thanks for the response. JWT bearer grant type seems a reasonable choice, given that I'd like to stick to the product's functionality as much as possible, without too much customization.
I'll have to exchange the token eventually with the bearer grant type, as described in your blog post. Where do you expect that call to happen? Ideally I'd like to use it on the client side, when the external JWT is refreshed. But I'm not sure if this compromises the Applications's security, exposing client id and secret in the browser.

Comment: Disabling all Grant Types apart from JWT in the Application should limit the token generation to JWT Bearer requests only. Hence generating WSO2 tokens only for valid 3rd party tokens, which are validated by the configured Identity Provider. Even though the client secret is used on the frontend side, WSO2 token generation is only working in combination with a valid 3rd party access token, which should limit the secrets exposure. Maybe we will add a distinct unprotected service to handle token swapping on the server side. Anyway, it is working, thanks!

Comment: Using the suggested method without setting a proper scope while exchanging the tokens will invalidate older tokens. Swapping tokens directly from the Frontend is hence a no go, since you can't control which scope will be set eventually.
We introduced an additional backend service to check the 3rd party's issuer domain and properly set the scope. You also have to check the issuer, otherwise another compatible 3rd party token could be used to generate valid tokens for your app.